# Windows phone 8.1 storage fail

Tags: 8.1, lumia-520, storage

My mother phone was running out of space for a long time. She tried to install some stickers app from windows phone and obviously due to lack of storage it is stuck in the process.

From that point my troubles go on.

First of all I cannot enter into most of the apps on my phone. Only some simple setting app work.

For example I can turn on and off wifi, set date to on and off and do the simple operation. I am litteraly out of space but everytime I delete facebook, messenger the phone restarts and reverts to old settings.

I have searched all over the internet and I cannot find the solution. There are lots of photos on this phone and I just want to save them. Unfortunately whilst my PC can see the device when I double open the windows phone there is nothing to show.

Please tell me if there is any trick to connect to file system by interop unlock of phone. Anything will do really as I just want to save the files.

Thanks

Comment: What phone does she have? Does it have expandable storage (micro SD)? Has the phone been set to upload photos to OneDrive (or some other cloud service)? If not, can you upload them manually through the Photos app?

Comment: Lumia 520. As noted as soon as I open any real app phone restarts by itself. This stupid stickers app is giving me a huge headaches. If only I could somehow remotely stop the installation since I cannot enter the store. Thank you for  your support. Phone litteraly has about 3mb of free space and while inserting sd cards it asks me do you I want to switch my files to it. Unfortunately it restarts shortafter. I inserted small 2GB card I will try with larger one. But I am afraid it will restart again. I have never seen this in my life that I cannot delete app from WP...

Comment: Even if I delete the app and then manually restart short after it is still the same thing all apps reverted.. PRobably it is a memory problem. When I coonect it to PC it displays correctly the space but when i enter into the folder I cannot see anything...

Comment: Are you saying that when you try to uninstall an app, the phone restarts and the app is back? Sounds like you need to do a hard reset to get it back to working order (which will of course wipe any files and other user data). Have you checked whether the photos are on OneDrive? Can you open the storage settings (look around in Settings, I don't have a WP8.1 device at hand right now) and free up some space from there?

Comment: It seems so... No I am afraid not. I think I had backup option turned on but obviously that won't return all the photos and videos. I cannot open anything. Very weird bug I have not seen something like this in my life. I will now try to put an 16gb sd card in hope that it may start putting files there.

Comment: I have found out about windows phone power tools. It seems that it can remotely unninstall windows phone apps from phone. If I could unninstall this cursed app that is currently installing. That would be gr8.

Comment: I have found out about WPInternals and it seems that I can enter mass storage mode with this way.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the bug in question is abotu write protected memory. It is only possible to reflash it with JTAG device.